# In CloudKit, how to get only some of the fields, not all, of found records?

Tags: xcode, cloudkit

In Apple's CloudKit, is there any way to get only some of the fields, not all, of found records?

There is a method, - fetchRecordWithID:completionHandler:, in the class CKDatabase. But it seems that it gets all the fields of found records.

I want this because of performance consideration. I am developing an app that can store some files in iCloud. The user usually wants to see the list of the files, and then choose one to download. But if all the fields are to be downloaded, all the files have to be downloaded before the list can be shown, since a file is a field (CKAsset) of the file's record.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `-fetchRecordWithID:completionHandler:` on `CKDatabase`, you should instead create a [`CKFetchRecordsOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKFetchRecordsOperation_class/index.html) and set the `desiredKeys` property to only the names of the fields you want to fetch.